# How to view/edit data in Sharepoint List if there are more than 5000 records?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

We are reviewing in term of storing a business data into Sharepoint List againts tradional SQL database. We noticed that there is limitation on the view (5000 records) in Sharepoint List within Sharepoint itself.

My question is there any tools that we can view/edit/delete records for Sharepoint List as if like SQL Server Management Studio where you can filter the data and then delete/edit the data in bulk ?

I'm appreciated your input.

Comment: You can create multiple filtered views

Comment: The 5000 row limit is configurable via Sharepoint Central Admin, under web app -> General Settings -> Throttling. You can edit multiple items as @vinayakhegde says and also with Microsoft Access

Answer (score 0):

If Microsoft Access can access the list (as per above) and I assume that the SQL Management can access this also then? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can increase the list view Threshold limit beyond **5000** but it is **not a best practice** and it is **recommended that you should not alter this value**, as it may degrade the performance.

Instead there are many ways to handle this like :

1. Create Indexed columns
2. Limit items on display
3. Create folders to organize items
4. Create filtered views (as suggested/commented by vinayak hegde)

Please refer these links :

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-11ecc804-2284-4978-8273-4842471fafb7

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/quentin/2014/07/15/the-list-view-threshold-stop-dont-change-it/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Throttling

Answer (score 0):

SQL Management Studio cannot access list in SharePoint!

*(Well, actually... you can access items with SQLMS directly in the tables in the database, but that is strictly forbidden by Microsoft and doing so breaks the support of the product and can cause unexpected behaviour and errors. Just don't do it!)*

You can safely use the lists own Quick Edit mode, where you can do bulk editing similar to editing an Excel sheet.

Quick Edit can be done in a list with more than 5000 items.

Enable Quick Edit by going to 
List settings > Advanced Settings > Quick Edit and tick "Yes" to allow items in list to be edited using Quick Edit.